# Key SPACE acts like focused button

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

Whenever SPACE key is pressed, it is registered and processed as a last pressed (focused) button. I cannot capture it as KeyEvent, and it acts as a button.

I want to generate and pass on char from buttons and keyboard keys pressed.

Here is the handler part of my code in the controller class:

```
public void handleKeys(KeyEvent key) {
    char chr = key.getText().charAt(0);
    handleSymbols(chr);
    key.consume();
}

public void handleBtns(ActionEvent buttonPressed) {
    char chr = buttonPressed.getSource().toString().toLowerCase().charAt(buttonPressed.getSource().toString().length() - 2);
    handleSymbols(chr);
    buttonPressed.consume();
}
```

Here is the FXML file beginning:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <?import javafx.geometry.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

 <BorderPane fx:id="container" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="400.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00e600"
        stylesheets="/sample/main.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="sample.Controller"
        onKeyPressed="#handleKeys">

<left>
    <VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="50.0">
        <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
        </BorderPane.margin>

            <Button onAction="#handleBtns" prefHeight="135.0" prefWidth="50" text="+">
                <VBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="20.0" />
                </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button onAction="#handleBtns" prefHeight="135.0" prefWidth="50" text="-" />

    </VBox>
</left>
```

There is something similar here, but for SWING, so it does not work:[Disabling space bar triggering click for JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472530/jbutton-referring-to-space-bar-the-same-as-a-click)

How can i unbind SPACE as a default key for focused buttons? I just don't want SPACE to act as a button.

Comment: @James_D, maybe you know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added an eventFilter to the stage in the main class and it works

```
addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, k -> {
        if ( k.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE){
            k.consume();
        }
    });
```